# QThread not work correctly and pyqt gui application freeze

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I'm writing python gui application that process a image and send image color from serial port and show the results but unfortunately my gui freeze. i try using QApllication.processEvents and it is work but my program speed slow and speed is so important to me and every one second one iteration should be complete And then i use QThread and my application still freeze. Here is my code:

```
class Worker(QObject):

    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    gui_update = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, knot, lay, baft):
        super().__init__()
        self.knot = knot
        self.lay = lay
        self.baft = baft

    def run(self):

        while self.knot <= knotter_width:
            color_to_send = []
            for i in range(1, number_of_knotter + 1):
                color_to_send.append(self.baft["knotters"][i][self.lay][self.knot])

            self.progress.emit(self.knot)
            self.gui_update.emit() # for updating gui but not work
```

QThread setups:

```
self.thrd = QThread()
    self.worker = Worker(self.knot, self.lay, self.baft)
    self.worker.moveToThread(self.thrd)
    self.thrd.started.connect(self.worker.run)
    self.worker.progress.connect(self.progress)
    self.worker.gui_update.connect(self.knotters_status)
    self.worker.finish.connect(self.finished)
    self.worker.ex.connect(self.thrd.quit)
    self.worker.ex.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
    self.thrd.finished.connect(self.thrd.deleteLater)

    self.thrd.start()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @G.M. I editted.

Comment: Still the provided code is open ended. Many variables still not justified like self.worker.ex

And one more thing, sometimes back I had faced issue with Qthread and freezing when I was bombarding the events too much. As a remedy, I collected my data in a list and emitted only when they reached a certain count. And then at the end when process is over I emitted the remaining list

Comment: I answered question in my other posts https://stackoverflow.com/a/70624220/14985100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days of research i found that after setting up thread you need to call **processEvents()** just after creating thread object and in that situation it doesn't cause slowing down and every thing work perfectly.
note: you should put the parameters in **init** function.

this is my final code:

```
class Thrd(QThread):

progress = pyqtSignal(int)
gui_update = pyqtSignal()
finish = pyqtSignal(bool)
ex = pyqtSignal()

def __init__(self, knot, lay, baft):
    super().__init__()
    self.knot = knot
    self.lay = lay
    self.baft = baft

def run(self):

    while condition:

        # some process

        self.progress.emit(self.knot)
        self.gui_update.emit()
        time.sleep(0.05) # give a little time to update gui

    self.finish.emit(True)
    self.ex.emit()
```

And setting up part:

```
self.thrd = Thrd(self.knot, self.lay, self.baft)
app.processEvents()
self.thrd.progress.connect(self.progress)
self.thrd.gui_update.connect(self.knotters_status)
self.thrd.finish.connect(self.finished)
self.thrd.ex.connect(self.thrd.quit)
self.thrd.finished.connect(self.thrd.deleteLater)
self.thrd.finished.connect(self.stop)
self.thrd.start()
```